# Library to calculate date in Javascript

Tags: javascript, date, methods, lib

I have a question about a method to calculate total days by javascript.
Example:
- startDate = 20170916 and closeDate = 20171224 => 99 days

What libs can I use to write this method? 
Note that can't use moment.js libs and I'm a newbie of js

Comment: @JonasLochmann this is a request of requirement, not using moment.js

Comment: Have you [searched for similar questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjavascript%5D+%5Bdate%5D+difference+between+dates+in+days)?

Comment: Ok, let me take a look. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why bother with a library for something this simple?

Just subtract `startDate` ms from `closeDate` ms and then divide by ms in a day:

```js
var msInADay = 86400000,
  startDate = new Date("2017-09-16"),
  closeDate = new Date("2017-12-24"),
  daysBetween = (closeDate.getTime() - startDate.getTime()) / msInADay;
console.log(daysBetween + " days between");
```

Comment: Given the [number of duplicates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3224834/get-difference-between-2-dates-in-javascript), you probably should have marked it as a duplicate.

Comment: @RobG I did, and if it gets enough votes it will close, but until then this answers the question.